# Convertion varchar field (dd/mm/yyy) to datetime format

Tags: sql, datetime, data-conversion

i have the following table of the picture  and i try to convert  the NEWPHASEdt varchar to datetime example 2022-16-09 00:00:00.000 an i get error

> The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

[image]

Comment: don't save dates as varchar and you will have less problem, i thin  you are using sql server, but that is onl y a guess

Comment: Save a DateTime always as a datetime, not as string/varchar.

Comment: Show us your current code attempt.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Answer (score 0):

My solution is to use:

```
CONVERT(DATETIME, NEWPHASEdt, 103)
```

Comment: Better use `Try_convert` unless you want to get errors on every incompatible value.